# Cypress cy.setCookie() won't properly save the cookie on production

Tags: cookies, cypress, samesite, cookie-httponly

Quick context: I've implemented a cookie consent banner and now all the current E2E test are showing it, so I've added it to a beforeEach and my banner reads from `cookies-js` as `Cookies.get("cookies_consent")` to show/hide the banner.

```js
    cy.setCookie(
        "cookies_consent",
        JSON.stringify({
          cookies_analytics: isGranted ? "granted" : "denied",
          cookies_marketing: isGranted ? "granted" : "denied",
        }),
        {
          hostOnly: true,
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: "lax",
        }
      );
```

Everything works in localhost.

But when in production (Cypress cloud), the banner keeps showing as there weren't any cookies.

When on development the domain is `localhost`, on deploy the domain can change because our CI, could be business.deploy-1000.com, business.deploy-1001.com.., until it's published.

- Changing property options from https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie
- Using `Cookies.set` from `cookies-js` in Cypress instead of `cy.setCookie`.
- Investigated these issues to remove the prepend dot on the domain:

  - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1896
  - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/25174
  - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/25853

Comment: What happens if you skip 
```hostOnly: true,
          httpOnly: true,
          sameSite: "lax"```

Comment: That’d be even worst because the domain would prepend a dot